# How to find database transactional discrepancies

Tags: database, data-analysis, data-cleaning

**Background:**
I have an application with sales and store transaction management, the application is quite well and working as per the customer's requirements for a long period.(Dev Set is VB6, SQL Server 2008 R2 and Crystal reports 2010 etc)
**Problem Statement :**
Recently, I have received a complaint from my customer about the store values of a product is not accurate, while compared to physical store and reports.

**Corrective Actions Taken to Resolve the Issue:**
Application transactions are checked by testing sales, sales return, stock in out and stock transfer from one store to other but not find any evidence to rectify the issue answer, Now to solve this issue and continue business process, I have to manually compare the stock values to balance the stock/store values.

**Expected Solution :**

1. How can I figure out this type of data discrepancy issues as all the
   mandatory checks are in place.
2. Adding to above, is there any tool that can monitor this type of data error automatically?
3. Another thing is, how can we use data analysis tools using AI(Data Science) to predict data
   discrepancies if possible.

Please help me and give your valuable suggestion and share your experiences, regards.

Comment: Did you find the root cause of the discrepancy between physical stock and data. Are you sure that it's a data problem?Is someone stealing from the store? Are some of the stock movements not recorded? You may need to do add logging to the application to detect errors that may be causing transactions to fail, etc

Comment: Mustafa ...  thanks for your suggestions. Store transfer transactions are also logged and analysed it is the part of the system. What I want to generate the scenario when this happens, which is not possibly identified yet or a tool that can identify it by analysing data please.

Comment: I don't know of any such tool. But if you log every transaction and compare it to the total count of goods at the end of the day you'll either find a problem with the transactions or discover that goods are stolen.